# Can I get programmatic access to wp-admin?

Tags: wp-admin, rest-api, configuration

I need to script configuration for an existing Wordpress site. Does `wp-admin` provide any kind of API for programmatic access? (Installing a local wrapper for access would be fine.)

For example, to change the site title or enable/disable an installed plugin.

Comment: Sounds like you want [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org). There's APIs for everything else in `wp-admin` but it depends what you want to do, and you'd need to be logged in normally first.

Comment: @JacobPeattie looks great, do you want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: WP Admin uses all the same core APIs, you'd be better just setting options directly rather than trying to do programmatic access to WP Admin which is at the end of the day just a GUI

Comment: @TomJNowell do you mean directly modifying values in configuration files?

Comment: @d3vid more directly would be changing the options in the database, WP CLI just provides a convenient way to do that